# I can't use the Menu in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, menu, pysimplegui

I want to add a feature to change the background using the menu but it doesn't work. When I click on any menu item, nothing happens, the background doesn't change and it doesn't print anything. Maybe I'm also doing the background change in a wrong way, so, if someone could help me, I would be happy.

This is my code:

```
from time import sleep
import os
try:
    import PySimpleGUI as sg
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    os.system('pip3 install PySimpleGUI')
import sys

theme = ('dark grey 9')

sg.theme(theme)

menu_def = [['Customize GUI', ['Background', ['White::white', 'Purple::purple']]]]

layout = [[sg.Menu(menu_def)]]

window = sg.Window('Fast reader by Hary', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == 'Purple::purple':
        theme = 'LightPurple'
        window.refresh()
    elif event == 'White::white':
        theme = 'DarkGrey6'
        window.refresh()
```

Comment: "just typing some random things..."—please don't do this. "the site says me to add some more details"—so maybe _add some more details?_ The rules are here to help _you_ as much as us. Asking a good question greatly increases the chances that you'll get a helpful response. Please read [ask], paying particular attention to the [mcve] part (emphasis on "minimal") and the part asking you to pretend you're talking to a busy colleague. Show some respect for our time.

Comment: k, sorry, I didn't know what to type but  I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `'Menu item::optional_key'` as event in your event loop.

There're sub-menu under menu, so no easy setting for background color of all items in menu.

There're something wrong in your code

- Method `sg.theme(theme)`only work before window finalized
- Different value of user variable `theme` won't change the theme state.
- Method `window.refresh()` is not required if next statement will be `window.read()` which will update window.

For new theme and new setting for Menu, new window will be preferred. Demo code as following,

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def main_window(theme, background_color, window=None):

    sg.theme(theme)

    menu_def = [['Customize GUI', ['Background', ['White::white', 'Purple::purple']]]]
    layout = [[sg.Menu(menu_def, key='-MENU-', text_color='black', background_color=background_color)]]
    new_window = sg.Window('Fast reader by Hary', layout, finalize=True)
    if window is not None:
        window.close()
    return new_window

theme, background_color = 'DarkGrey9', 'green'
window = main_window(theme, background_color)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Purple::purple':
        theme, background_color = 'LightPurple', 'purple'
        window = main_window(theme, background_color, window)
    elif event == 'White::white':
        theme, background_color = 'DarkGrey6', 'white'
        window = main_window(theme, background_color, window)

window.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
if menu_def == 'purple':
```

The variable `menu_def` is a whole list, it cannot be equal to `purple`. I believe you meant to say `if event == 'Purple'`?

Comment: @zHary_ Kindly check edit. I'm not the most familiar with this library, but I guess you need to use `"Purple"` (uppercase), since your menu button is called like that. Otherwise, simply try `print(event)` right after the `window.read()`, this will tell you what the exact string you're looking for should be.

Comment: I did it. The event is "Purple::purple", it worked, it actually prints the "It worked!" but the background does not change.

Comment: Searching, I discovered that I probably can't change the background color of this window... If you know any way to do that, tell me but I think it's impossible.